# PyTorch second derivative is zero everywhere

Tags: pytorch

I'm working on a custom loss function that requires me to compute the trace of the hessian matrix of a neural network with respect to its inputs.

In one dimension, this reduces to the second derivative of the network with respect to its input. Suppose my network is `u` and my input is `x`. The problem is completely one-dimensional, so the relationship I'm trying to model is `u(x)` where `u` has one input and one output, and `x` is one-dimensional. However, I'm running with batches, so `x` "comes in" as a column vector and I'm expecting a column vector as output.

If we label the samples in the batch as `x_1, x_2, ..., x_n`, I'm thus interested in the following vectors:

[image]     [image]

In PyTorch, I have tried the following:

```
u = model(x)
d = grad(u, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u), create_graph=True)[0]
dd = grad(d, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(d), retain_graph=True, create_graph=False)[0]
```

This works well for u' but u'' comes out as being zero everywhere:

[image]

I'm a bit confused on the whole notion of needing a vector jacobian product here to begin with. Should I view the computation as `u` mapping from `R^n` to `R^n`, where `n` is the size of my batch?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: doesn't du/dx seem incorrect too? between 1 and 2 it should be rather constant, doesn't it?

Comment: I agree with you it looks a bit "wrong," so earlier I tried interpolating `u` and calculating a numerical derivative with scipy. With enough points, the plots look the same. So I believe the derivative is probably correct. I used relatively few points in the plot, so my guess is that there is some curvature that would be visible if more points were used. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Toy example

I have tried to devise a toy example for you:

```py
x = torch.rand(3, requires_grad=True).reshape(-1, 1)
u = x ** 2.

# du/dx = 2 * x
dx = torch.autograd.grad(u, x, torch.ones_like(u), retain_graph=True, create_graph=True)[0]

# d^2 u/dx^2 = 2
ddx = torch.autograd.grad(dx, x, torch.ones_like(u))[0]
```

These are the outputs of `x`, `dx`, `ddx`:

```py
tensor([[0.5217],
        [0.0400],
        [0.5509]], grad_fn=<ReshapeAliasBackward0>)
tensor([[1.0434],
        [0.0800],
        [1.1018]], grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
tensor([[2.],
        [2.],
        [2.]])
```

So `grad` is computing the gradient of `x` *element-wise*.

##### Should I view the computation as u mapping from R^n to R^n, where n is the size of my batch?

My answer is no, otherwise `dx` should have been a Jacobian matrix instead of a vector.

##### This works well for u' but u'' comes out as being zero everywhere

Given the limited context, the only thing I can think of is that the second derivative of `model(x)` with respect to `x` is zero.

Comment: Actually, I believe you're right. I did some more plotting just now and I think I may have been fooled by having too many points involved. If I limit the number of points, my model produces a piecewise constant function (which of course has a zero second derivative almost everywhere). With a very high number of points the function just looks like it's smooth(-ish). Thank you